# GTK+ Overlay not display childs in correct order

Tags: widget, gtk, gtkoverlay

https://github.com/nintyfan/V2BlankBrowser

In file main. See at v1UI_integration branch and init_v1_ui and real_new_tab code. I known, there is big amount of code, so I do not paste it here.

Problem is, when trying to add more than two children to GtkOverlay, one of it always get at index 0 and I cannot reorder it with gtk_overlay_reorder_overlay. I try with different approach by use three overlays (one root and two children) and it worked, but problem was I cannot interact with items, even when setting gtk_overlay_set_overlay_pass_through to children. What i do wrong?

Comment: Ok. I see I must set gtk_overlay_set_overlay_pass_through after adding overlay to parent. Logical. Sorry.

Comment: Please consider writing an answer to your question, since you've figured out the problem.

Comment: Yes, but I figured only partial solution. I do not known, why I cannot reorder child of overlay and have to grouping overlay to makes things done.

Comment: I would suggest providing a minimal and reproducible example we can try. I have no intention of reading through your codebase and probably others won't either.